# Use string values in Win API call

Tags: windows, assembly, winapi, x86-64

I'm trying to use the MessageBoxA Windows API as shown here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messageboxa

When executing the following, and `r15` is MessageBoxA, I get a successful execution of the API, but with no values.

```
xor rcx, rcx
xor rdx, rdx
xor r8, r8
xor r9, r9
call r15
```

When i try to assign string values in the text field, it fails to execute and i'm not sure why.

```
xor rcx, rcx
mov rdx, 0x0041414141
xor r8, r8
xor r9, r9
call r15
```

I can use a variable defined in the `.data` section and it works fine but I want to figure out how to do it without `.data` sections.

E.g.

```
section .data
    aaaa db 'AAAA',0
...
mov rdx, aaaa
```

Comment: Constructing a string from immediate data (like `mov reg, imm64` / `push reg`) is common in shellcode.  For a 4-byte string, `push 'AAAA'` will zero-extend to 64-bit, then `mov rdx, rsp`.  You of course need a pointer in RDX, not bytes of string data.

Comment: @PeterCordes that's got me closer but not sure what's going wrong now as it's not printing AAAA. `mov rdx, 0x41414141` `push rdx` `lea rdx, [rsp]` `add rsp 8`. Here i have pushed imm64 to the stack, loaded the address into RDX and corrected the stack pointer

Comment: in x64 you can use `createAstring macro name, string
name proc
 lea rax,@@1
 ret
@@1:
 DB string,0
name endp
endm` in x86 - `createAstring macro name, string
@CatStr(_,name) proc
  call @@1
  DB string,0
@@1:
  pop eax
  ret
@CatStr(_,name) endp
endm`

Comment: I think i solved my previous point by pushing twice, but pushing a null byte first and then incrementing by `0x10`, not sure if there's a better way

Comment: @jord Remove the `add rsp, 8`. Your function call overwrites the string with the return address, so the function ends up reading garbage. You should only clean up the stack once it's contents are not needed. In C terminology that would be a dangling pointer (but a sort of weird one because it points to the stack).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MessageBoxA` function requires its string argument to be in memory, not in a register. Since you don't want it in the `.data` section, we can use the stack:

```
mov  edx, 'AAAA' ; zeroes the upper half of rdx so it is null-terminated
push rdx
mov  rdx, rsp

sub  rsp, 32 ;  Reserve shadow space: the callee can overwrite these bytes

xor ecx, ecx
xor r8d, r8d
xor r9d, r9d
call r15
add rsp, 40    ; free the shadow space and the string
```

The string needs to live on the stack for the entire duration of the function call, it cannot be popped earlier.

And it can't be in the shadow space that the callee might overwrite before reading the pointed-to memory, which is why we `push` *before* reserving shadow space.

Remember to have RSP aligned by 16 before the `call` since the Windows x64 calling convention requires that.  This means doing an odd number of 8-byte adjustments since function entry, counting pushes and `sub rsp, constant`.  If you'd already done an odd number of pushes before you want to `push` some ASCII bytes, you could `sub rsp, 40` instead of `sub rsp, 32`, and adjust the `add rsp, 40` the same amount to undo it.

In this case, `push 'AAAA'` would have the same effect as `mov edx, 'AAAA'` / `push rdx`.  The only two operand-sizes supported by `push` are 16 and 64-bit, and NASM defaults to 64-bit unless you tell it otherwise.  `push imm32` sign-extends the immediate to 64-bit, and `'A'` has its sign-bit zeroed, so we'll get a zero-terminated string from sign-extending it just like zero-extending.

Comment: You need to `mov rdx, rsp` directly after the `push rdx`.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: `push 'AAAA'` Just Works, no need for `mov reg, imm32` into a register first, because ASCII characters have their high bit cleared and thus sign-extension is the same as zero-extension.

Answer (score -1):

if use x86  you cam use next fragment in self code:

```
    call @@0
    DB 'some demo string',0
@@0:
    pop ecx ; or another register, in which you need get address of string
```

(or just left it in stack for pass to api call)

or you can use such macro

```
createAstring macro name, string
@CatStr(_,name) proc
  call @@1
  DB string,0
@@1:
  pop eax
  ret
@CatStr(_,name) endp
endm
```

and create function, which return address of string

```
createAstring some_string, 'some demo string'
```

and use it in code:

```
call _some_string
mov edx,eax ; or push eax, etc
```

this code can be used in x64 too, but here can be also simply used LEA, because it base independed

```
createAstring macro name, string
name proc
    lea rax,@@1
    ret
@@1:
    DB string,0
name endp
endm
```

or direct in code

```
    lea r8,@@1
    ...
@@1:
    DB 'aaa bbb ccc...',0
```

Comment: This is MASM syntax.  It appears the OP is using NASM, since they used `mov rdx, symbol_name` (`aaaa` in the question) to put a pointer into a register.  NASM macro syntax is different.  (And you need `default rel` for `lea rdx, [.string]` to use a RIP-relative addressing mode).  Also, for your final version with just LEA from nearby bytes in the .text section, you forgot to mention that the string needs to be after the end of the function, or before the start; somewhere that execution won't fall into it.  Because unlike the call/pop trick, nothing jumps over it. The `...` is rest of the func?

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, this is *MASM* syntax, but i think that this is not important here,  question not in this. in *MASM* not need *default rel*,  *you forgot to mention that* - but i thinked that this is obvious, so not direct mention this. and yes - under `...` i mean some another instructions in code